# Is there anyway to safely clean up local Firebase project folder?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cli

I'm new to Firebase. Recently, in order to fix certain errors, I tried many different ways until I feel that **my local project folder is pretty much messed up**, which could cause more other hidden problems. For example, I keep running `npm init` on many different folders, sometimes manually edited the `package.json` file, run `npm install firebase@5.9.4 --save` on several different folders and so on.

So I wonder, is there a way (or tool) that we can scan through our project folder and safely clean it up, e.g. remove redundant/unused dependencies, e.g. `node_modules`, add required dependencies, fix declarations/referencing errors, and so on without removing user-created assets like .js, .css, images etc.? I want to do that is because I believe this could potentially **reduce many hidden problems** and help to narrow down my troubleshooting tasks...

Alternatively, can I do the following:

1. Backup all my JS files.
2. Empty my Firebase's **functions** folder.
3. run `firebase init` again.
4. Restore my JS files.
5. Deploy and troubleshoot my Firebase functions again? Or any steps missing?

Sorry for a silly question. Any advice would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think there is a problem with the contents of your node_modules folder:

1. Remove all node_modules folders completely.  They don't contain any special information.  It is just copies of modules downloaded from the internet.
2. Rebuild it completely with `npm install` from the correct location (your functions folder), which uses your package.json to determine what it should contain.

Comment: But how can we be sure that our `package.json` is correct? `npm init` to rebuild it again? For the `npm install` that you mentioned, do we need to specify the package name, e.g. `npm install <package_name>` ? No need?

Comment: You determine if your package.json is correct.  There are tools to help you manage it, but you are ultimately responsible for it, since it describes what your project should contain.

Comment: I will try out your suggestion and see how it goes, thanks.

Comment: Your suggestion has helped me to solve some of my problems (although not all). I'm new to Node.js too, now only I know `npm install` is actually by default goes according to the `package.json`, thanks a lot!